# Incoming call screen is not displaying on Moto G 2nd gen

Tags: calls, screen, motorola-moto-g

I have Moto G 2nd gen. I can't see incoming call display screen on phone. Before 1 day, the phone used to work properly. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you covering the screen-off sensor during the call?

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Settings** -> **Apps** -> **All** -> **menu** and choose "**Reset app preferences**".